# Running file in IDLE window from command line directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-idle

So I'm able to open a file for editing with `IDLE` with the following command in (Windows) `cmd`:

```
python -m idlelib main.py
# not sure if there's a better way to do that
```

But, is there a way to run the file and have it's output open a new IDLE window (or switch to current one if any are open) directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `-r` option described in the help section:

```
USAGE: 
   idle  [-deins] [-t title] [file]*
   idle  [-dns] [-t title] (-c cmd | -r file) [arg]*
   idle  [-dns] [-t title] - [arg]*

-h         print this help message and exit
-n         run IDLE without a subprocess (DEPRECATED,
           see Help/IDLE Help for details)

The following options will override the IDLE 'settings' configuration:

-e         open an edit window
-i         open a shell window

The following options imply -i and will open a shell:

-c cmd     run the command in a shell, or
-r file    run script from file

-d         enable the debugger
-s         run $IDLESTARTUP or $PYTHONSTARTUP before anything else
-t title   set title of shell window
....
```

So, you'd do:

```
python -m idlelib -r main.py
```